# split serial output in kernel space

Tags: c, linux, kernel, openwrt

I am developing some code on a openwrt router and I receive some data on the serial port /dev/ttyS0 . The data that I receive is from different sources and is parsed by different user space applications.

I would like to split this data into N serial virtual ports where N=number of information sources (a source could be a temperature sensor, another source could be another sensor etc).

So I would like to have /dev/ttyS0 which is the main serial device and then /dev/ttyS1 , /dev/ttyS2 ... /dev/ttySN and each serial will output only the data from one information source.

I guess  that for this I would have to do some basic data parsing at kernel level. Do you know any source example that does something similar ?
The data is going in only one direction ... from sensors to the router, I don't need to send anything back so this will simplify things.

I'm opened to sugestions

Comment: Why do this in the kernel?  It seems as if it would be easier to have a single user-space process read the data from `ttyS0` and then expose the data to other code via sockets.

Comment: I need to have /dev/tty files because the other processes can only work with serial like devices

Comment: Are you certain they wouldn't work with, say, named pipes instead?

Comment: well the existing binaries take as input a file name that needs to point to a serial device

Comment: I guess you are right ... I can use named pipes. Thanks